# How to create event listeners in a for loop assigning to the dynamically created variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to make this working code:

```
                $('#link1').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#1'), 500); });
                $('#link2').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#2'), 500); });
                $('#link3').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#3'), 500); });
                $('#link4').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#4'), 500); });
                $('#link5').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#5'), 500); });
                $('#link6').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#6'), 500); });
                $('#link7').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#7'), 500); });
                $('#link8').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#8'), 500); });
                $('#link9').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#9'), 500); });
                $('#link10').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#10'), 500); });
                $('#link11').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#11'), 500); });
                $('#link12').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#12'), 500); });
                $('#link13').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#13'), 500); });
                $('#link14').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#14'), 500); });
                $('#link15').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#15'), 500); });
```

to be less long and silly looking. I wanted to create those event listeners with a for loop and that's what I came up with:

```
                for(var i=1; i<=15 ; i++ ){
                    var linkName1 = '#link'+i;
                    var linkName2 = '#'+i;
                    $(linkName1).click(function() { $.scrollTo($(linkName2), 500); });
                }
```

but right now it's assigning #15 to every link. I know that's a problem with scope. How to make it work?

Comment: Use a closure , or `let` as shown in duplicate link. At the time the event occurs the loop has been long completed and `i` is at it's maximum

Comment: @MPomianowski this not a good way to do that. I suggest you to it with one click event and add attribute to html element 
ex : 

`<span class='clickme' data-scroll='#15'></span>
$('.clickme').click(function() {
var data_scroll = $(this).attr('data-scroll');
 $.scrollTo($(data_scroll), 500);
});
`